# Server 2008 - Search for Files and Delete.. very slow!

Tags: windows-server-2008

Windows Server 2008 R2.  Old ish server (4 cores, 2GB RAM) fairly average disks running no raid.

I've used windows F, then searched for .svn files

Selected all, and deleting them.  631 files and 220MB.  It is going to take about 45mins to delete!!

**Problem:  How to delete files quickly?**

No antivirus or windows serach service running.  Out of the box install of 2008R2.  No other users on the system.  Using terminal services to admin onto the box as a development machine.

Cheers

Dave

Comment: did it really take 45 minutes to complete, or did you cancel the operation?

Comment: disks may have bad blocks. Any else is slow ? Or only file deletion? Raid is software raid or there is hardware raid? If hardware raid, is it with BBWC? what type of disks You have? In event log isn't anything aboud disks?

Comment: Good thoughts... a few years ago so no idea!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you delete or shift-delete? If you delete to recycle bin it takes longer. Try shift-deleting. Plus: check whether recycle bin is full, if so it takes even longer deleting old files from bin while deleting the .svn folders.

Answer (score 0):

A script might be a faster way to accomplish this, especially if you're going to do this multiple times.

for /f “tokens=* delims=” %%i in (’dir /s /b /a:d *.svn’) do (
 del /q “%%i”
)

Comment: or from the root: del *.svn /s